# Fixed Point Arithmetic: Why does the fp work sometimes but others it errors?

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, fp

Why does `fixed point arithmetic` like to error on parts of the code that aren't doing any math?

I am using the package to improve the calculation of some angles I have it printing out, but it is evaluating a node that is just a number and returning an error:

```
ERROR: FP error: Illegal character \c@pgf@counta  found in float number!.

--- TeX said ---
\FP@errmessage #1->\errmessage {FP error: #1!}

l.13   {};

--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.
```

---

```
\documentclass[convert = false, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{fp}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fixed point arithmetic]
  \node[label = x] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

From the code above, we see that `fp` has an issue with this node.  If I remove `fp`, there isn't a problem, but I want the package to be used later on in the code where there is an actual calculation.

Comment: Where do you actually need `fp`? On the labeled node path? The `label` key does some computations that are apparently forwarded to `fp`. You can move the `fixed point arithmetic` as an option to a path, i.e. `\path[fixed point arithmetic] <fancy calculations>;`, and don't use it on a node/a label.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel it is being used in the calculation of an arc in `draw let ... in` but shouldn't this not have a problem with a node?  I would think it should know where calculations occur.

Comment: AFAIK, `fixed point arithmetic` replaced all (?) PGF math functions with their `fp` counterparts (as a wrapper around the `\FP…` macros). The `label` key accesses the angular border of the node (it needs to know where to place the label). This uses the `cos` and `sin` functions (this is the reason you get the error message twice). The angle is calculated and result is stored in `\c@pgf@counta`. This `\c@pgf@counta` will be passed through the trigonometric functions to `fp` which doesn't like that. If you need `fp` only on the `let … in` part, use it only there.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel that is what I ended up doing (applying it to specified syntax only).  The weird thing is if I do all coordinates and label the them later from a draw command, there isn't a problem. `\coordinate (x) at (1, 0); \draw (0, 0) -- (x) node[above] {x};`

Comment: `above` which sets `anchor=south` doesn’t need to calculate a polar coordinate. Using `anchor=270` (even though the result is the same) triggers the error. For labels on circular unrotated nodes you can use the anchors instead of the compass directions, e.g. `north` instead of `above` (the default direction that is set with `label position`), `north west` instead of `above left`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you use the `fp` package instead of TikZ' own `fpu`?

Comment: @Jake I am not familiar with the syntax for `fpu` and it doesn't seem very intuitive.  With `fp`, it is a simple as saying `fixed point arithmetic`.

Comment: @dustin: Oh, I didn't know it was that simple with `fp`. That is indeed a lot more convenient. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### What happened?

When TikZ processes a `label` it needs to find the appropriate point on the border of the labeled node. A direction of `left` sets the anchor to the angle of `180`. Later down in this process the macro `\pgf@sh@reanchor` is used to find the actual coordinates of this point on the border.

This macro first checks if `180` is a named anchor for this shape (like `north west` or `base`), if it isn’t it is checked whether the anchor is a generic one. If it isn’t even a generic anchor it only can be a angular point on the border. `180` is then evaluated by `\pgfmathsetcounter`). The result is stored in the count register `\c@pgf@counta` (i.e. the LaTeX counter `pgf@counta`).

`\c@pgf@counta` is then directly used on `\pgfqpointpolar`. The `q` denotes a “quick” version of the `\pgfpointplar` macro which (the `q`uick version that is) does not parse its arguments but directly sends them to the the trigonometric functions. Usually this parsing and evaluating is done by PGF math which automatically detects registers like counts/counters, dimens and lengths/skips and properly expands them to their value (stripping away any units).

But the `fixedpointarithmetic` library and its option directly maps these trigonometric functions to their `fp` counterparts. `fp` does not tolerate registers.

#### A bug?

I consider this a bug in the definition of `\pgf@sh@reanchor` as seemingly every other use of `\pgfqpointpolar` of PGF uses directly numbers or content that expands to a number.

### *How to fix it?*

A **simple fix** using the [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package is:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% You should have loaded tikz before this line!
\patchcmd\pgf@sh@reanchor{\c@pgf@counta}{\the\c@pgf@counta}{}{}
```

This also fixes the direct use of angular anchors as in (keeping with your example):

```
\node at (P.90) {}; % or
\node[anchor=270] {};
```

#### `west` instead of `left`

For circular unrotated nodes you can actually use the compass anchors without a problem as they map directly to the directions. So instead of `left` you can use `west`. This will trigger the named anchors and avoids `\pgfqpointpolar`.

This usually does not work for other shapes, at least for the diagonal directions, as can be seen in the second TikZ picture.

#### Or you don’t use `fixed point arithmetic` for labels.

Of course, for this little task the `fp` package and its precision are not needed, so if you can avoid it, use `fixed point arithmetic` only on paths where you actually need it, say

```
\path[fixed point arithmetic] let <fancy calculations> in …;
```

If needed, you can construct a short-cut to that long option, say:

```
\tikzset{fp/.style={fixed point arithmetic={#1}},fp/.default=}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[convert = false, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{fp}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\pgf@sh@reanchor{\c@pgf@counta}{\the\c@pgf@counta}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fixed point arithmetic,
  every label/.append style = {font = \scriptsize},
  dot/.style = {inner sep = +0pt, shape = circle,
    draw = black, label = {#1}},
  small dot/.style = {minimum size = .05cm, dot = {#1}},
  big dot/.style = {minimum size = .1cm, dot = {#1}},
  ]
  \node[font = \scriptsize, small dot = {left: \(1\)}] (P) at (203.16381:3cm)
  {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[fill,minimum width=1cm,label = {[red]north west:nw}, label = {[green]above left:al}, label=north:n] (a){};
  \foreach \sty/\an in {white/north, green/135, red/north west}\path[draw=\sty,fill=black] (a.\an) circle [radius=.8pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Comment: So issuing `\patchcmd\pgf@sh@reanchor{\c@pgf@counta}{\the\c@pgf@counta}{}{}`, will allow me to use `fp` globally.  This is what I am getting from reading your post.  I do hope in a future update that node labelling can some how be removed from begin affected.

Comment: @dustin percusse has already opened a ticket at the bug report. It is just a matter of … months until a fix does make it in the official release version of PGF/TikZ. By the way, it does not only affect labels but every use of angular anchors by simply using `at (<node name>.<any angle>)` or, as commented above, in `anchor=<any angle>`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Till Tantau is doing a huge work with bug fixes recently. So hopefully it will get fixed quickly.

Answer (score 9):

TikZ uses the `\counter=\length` trick which would multiply the length (in pt) by 65536 to get an integer number of `sp` units (which egreg taught me). So it is very often that you can see the temporary TikZ counters `\c@pgf@counta...d` show up in the computations.

Here probably (I don't have the patience to wait for the `\tracingall` result), the polar coordinate computation involves a trigonometric computation and when `fp` takes over the math operations, it can't deal with it. Instead you can use the `fpu` library of TikZ itself which is also a little tedious to use but it's a native resident.

Here is an excerpt from a long code piece about how cosine operation comes to a halt.

```
\FPmul #1#2#3->\FP@callc \FP@mul #1{#2}{#3}
#1<-\pgfmathresult 
#2<-\c@pgf@counta 
#3<-0.017453292519943295
```

It was supposed to multiply the `#2` and `#3` and write it in `#1` but `#2` offends `fp`. This might be actually a bug in `fixed point aritmetic` library.

Comment: The particular error can be solved by doing `\the\c@pgf@counta` instead of `\c@pgf@counta`. Can `fp` trained to do this as well?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I think the problem comes from the fact that TikZ handles trigonometry very badly (often look up table) so to increase the precision switches to counter. It's not a problem for pgfmath because it checks wgether the argument is a counter or not but apparently forgot to switch back to length when calling `fp`. Oh and the answer to your question I really don't know.

Comment: A ticket is opened at https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/255/ for this in the PGF Bug Tracker